# animate hover affects non sibling element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, jquery-animate

http://julieparlade.com/Web2/Fox_And_Hound/Beers.html

For the above website page, I am trying to animate the beer image in the blue box when its descriptor in the red box is hovered over. The two elements are not close to each other as far as child/parent/sibling relationships so is there a way I can still make them affect each other?

**Below is what I have in my css**

```
    /*==========================
        Hover 1 affect another
        ==========================*/
        .text-box-stout{
            display: inline-block;
            -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: 1s ease-in-out;
            border: red 1px solid;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .stout-bottle{
        border: blue 1px solid;
        }

        .text-box-stout:hover + .stout-bottle{
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
            transform: rotate(5deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
            transform: rotate(-5deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
            transform: rotate(5deg);
        }
```

**Here is the html:**

```
        <!-- TOP ROW Logo, title, desciption, lager -->
        <article class="row"> 
            <div class="col-sm-3 box hidden-xs"> 
                <!-- Stout Text-->
                <div class= "opacity_4 text-box-stout">
                    <h5> The artful blending of six malts and months of aging keep this <span>stout </span> the toast of the winter season.</h5>        
                </div>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 box"> 
                <!-- Logo-->
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Fox and Hound Logo" id= "beerslogo">
                    </a>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 box"> 
                <!-- Lager-->
                <div class= "opacitybeer">
                    <img src="img/lager.png" alt="Lager" class="lager"> 
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 box"> 
                <!-- Title-->
                <div class= "opacity_lager2 visible-xs">
                        <div class="beers">
                            <a href="Beers.html">
                            <h2 >Home <br> Brewed<br> Since</h2>
                            </a>
                            <h3>2009</h3>   
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class= "opacity_lager2 lagertext">
                    <!-- Lager Text-->
                    <h5>
                        Smooth Character, hints of caramel and toast, and remarkable drinkability define this ruby-colored <span> lager</span>.
                    </h5>       
                </div>  
            </div>
        </article> 

        <article class="row"> 
                    <!-- Stout-->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 box visible-xs"> 
                <!-- Stout Text-->
                <div class= "opacity_lager4">
                    <h5> The artful blending of six malts and months of aging keep this <span>stout </span> the toast of the winter season.</h5>        
                </div>      
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 box stout-bottle">    
                <img src="img/stout.png" alt="stout" class="lager">
            </div>
```

Comment: With css you can't affect non-siblings/childs elements.

Comment: is this what you try ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwdMgd else , there is a way to select area to respond with :hover  using pointer-events properties,  it is quiet specific and can be no help in some cases (forms,link, selection, ...)

Comment: here an example with the pointer-events idea : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xbavvq , what best to draw a sketch ? hover title to see

Comment: the codepen example didn't work, when applied, it still is affecting the img directly next to the text. How would pointer-events properties work in this case?

Comment: wich browser do you use ?  about pointer-events, when a child is hovered, parents are too, pointer-events to none, filters where hover can be catch or not

Comment: Im using chrome, the animation worked, it just didn't animate what I wanted to target

Comment: okay, here another example where border is applied to h1 and img no matter wich you hover. not usable in real as such, but demonstrate the idea http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zxmOqN

Answer (score 0):

For your example and if the animatiom you want is as simple I would use this turnaround with a bit of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.button').hover(function () {
                $('.image').toggleClass("rotate")
            });
        });
```

basically you add to your "beer" an extra class whatever you hover on whatever container you choose to activate the animation.

In this **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fe0xycs9/1/)** you may see it better (as I explain myself poorly, not my main lenguaje, sorry):